# Access Denied when try to cast to SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11, shdocvw

This issue has emerged with IE 10 + (I am using IE 11). In IE 9, the following code does not generate an error.

The error I am getting is

> First-chance exception at 0x76afc41f (KernelBase.dll) in MyApp.exe: 0x80070005: Access is denied.

Here is the code snippet up to the point where the error occurs.

```
 private Browser GetBrowser()
{

    ShellWindows windows = null;
    IWebBrowser2 shellWindow =null;
    IHTMLDocument2 actualDoc = null;

    windows = new SHDocVw.ShellWindowsClass();
    bool found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < windows.Count; i++)
    {

        try{
            shellWindow = windows.Item(i) as SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2; //Breaks Here
```

I am thinking that there is some sort of new security feature in IE 10 that might be causing this to happen.

Does anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: Why are you not using the web browser control?

Comment: I can't answer that. This is a relatively big project and this is just an aspect of it. This code has been authored by someone else at another company before my company acquired it. We have just moved on from updating some of the core functionality onto some of these extra features, and we're looking to reuse code wherever possible. 

Are we still able to interact with IE 10 and up using a method similar to this?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/03/14/enhanced-protected-mode.aspx

Comment: Hans, I checked my settings and I do not have Enhanced Protection mode enabled.